# PostgreSQL 9.1 and Rails 3 database migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am using PostgreSQL 9.1, which I installed using the DMG provided on the Postgres website. So, my Postgres installation is in `/Library/Postgres/9.1`.

I am pretty sure my Postgres server is running, but when I run `rake db:migrate` the `rake` is aborted with this error:

```
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Why is "rake" searching `/var/...` and not using my installation of Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Can you supply the link from which you actually downloaded Postgres? It seems like your instance of Postgres has a differently-named socket file than Rails expects, so Rails is unable to find it.

One option is to find the socket that does exist on your system and create a symlink to it from the location mentioned in the output. But my suggestion is to delete this instance of Postgres and simply install it again using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) since you seem to be using OSX. Installation using Homebrew is straightforward: `brew install postgresql`. After completing the installation just follow the steps listed in the command line output to complete the installation.

Also, if you are using the Postgres.app provided by Heroku you may want to check [the documentation](http://postgresapp.com/documentation).